# Strip tags from text in Javascript and replace BR with linebreaks inside textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to import some formatted html text in a input textarea value

i use jquery

so what's the best way to do it?
i guess first off i need to replace the 
 then strip out the rest (bold, italic, images etc..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my first response I didn't see that you wanted to retain line breaks, so here's a better version. It replaces br with an unlikely string %%br%% and then at the end replaces them with new line (\n). So if that string actually appears in the text, it will be replaced by a new line. You can change that to anything you like, just make it something that is unlikely to be encountered in the text.

```
<script>

function removeMarkup(m) {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.innerHTML = m;
  var c = 0;

  // Make brString something that should never appear in the text
  // and has no special meaning in a RegExp
  var brString = '%%br%%'
  var re = new RegExp('\\s*' + brString + '\\s*','g');

  function getTextWithReturns(node) {

    var tag = node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase();
    var nodes = node.childNodes;
    var type = node.nodeType;
    var s = '';

    // Deal with br
    if (tag == 'br') {
      return brString;
    }

    if (nodes && nodes.length) {
      for (var i=0, iLen=nodes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        s += getTextWithReturns(nodes[i]);
      }
    } else if (type == 3 || type == 4) {
      s += node.nodeValue
    } 
    return s;
  }
  return reduceWhitespace(getTextWithReturns(d)).replace(re,'\n');
}

function reduceWhitespace(s) {
  return s.replace(/^\s*/,'').replace(/\s*$/,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');
}

</script>

<div id="d0">some text <i>more</i> text
  <p>Here is a paragraph with some <b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i> text, plus a <span>span</span> and a line break break break<br> about there.</p>
  <p>Here is another paragraph with some <b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i> text, plus plus a <span>span</span> and a line break <br> here.</p>
</div>

<form>
<textarea id="ta0" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="
  var ta = document.getElementById('ta0');
  var div = document.getElementById('d0');
  ta.value = removeMarkup(div.innerHTML);
">Set value</button><input type="reset">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#my_textarea").change(function(){
    var cleanText = $("<span />").html(this.value);
    this.value = cleanText.text();
});
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6WbXN/**

Comment: innerText is a proprietary Microsoft property that is not supported by all browsers. The (roughly) equivalent W3C DOM property is textContent. However, white space and line breaks are handled differently, some kind of regular expression or replace should be used to normalise it.

Comment: Which one handles line breaks differently? `textContent` or `innerText`? And does my edit fix the cross-browser issue?

Comment: They are different from each other. Incidentally, jQuery uses neither, it recurses over child nodes looking for text nodes and concatenating their values. That is a reasonable strategy, but usually slower than using textContent or innerText where available.